# Yii2. Если таблица представлена двумя моделями, как сделать связь hasOne с выбором одной из этих моделей?

Tags: php, yii2

Поясню довольно сложный заголовок вопроса:
Работаем на Yii2.
У нас есть 1 большая таблица "компании". Компания может быть разных типов: компания клиент, компания продавец, компания банк и тд. тип определяется полем type в таблице компаний.
Для каждого из типов сделана своя модель и 1 базовая для всех компаний.
В этих моделях переопределены методы из общей компании. Ну и тд.

Но у нас есть модель документ. Документ может быть привязан к компании. У одного документа может быть одна компания. Как это сделать с нашей структурой?
Пример связи:

```
public function getClientCompany(): ActiveQuery
{
      return $this->hasOne(ClientCompany::className(), ['id' => 'company_id']);
}
```

Здесь сделана связь к компании клиента. Но как сделать связь, которая в зависимости от поля type, возвращала бы нам объект типа нужного нам типа?

```
public function getCompany(): ActiveQuery
{
      return $this->hasOne(BaseCompany::className(), ['id' => 'company_id']);
}
```

Мы не можем сделать связь с BaseCompany, т.к. это абстрактный класс, по идее он должен работать интерфейсом. Но не знаю как это сделать со связями.
Если связь hasMany, то эту проблему можно обойти, я просто создаю несколько методов getClientCompany, getAgentCompany и тд. И потом я точно могу знать, кто и что мне вернет. Но когда есть только одна компания, то я не знаю как это сделать.

Я знаю что это довольно сложный вопрос для понимания слету и со стороны. Но возможно вы сможете мне накидать идей для раздумий.

Answer (score 0):

Доброе утро.
А что Вам мешает добавить условие в связь?

Например так

```
public function getCompany(): ActiveQuery
{
  return $this->hasOne(BaseCompany::className(), ['id' => 'company_id'])
              ->andWhere(['type' => 'type_company');
}
```

Comment: да можно так, но мне тогда придется сделать метод getClientCompany(), getAgentCompany() и тд. А хочется так что бы один метод возвращал объект нужного типа.

Comment: через скап можем связаться?

Comment: у меня нет микрофона, если только текстом отвечать буду